# Where in the Ruby docs is the line continuation operator (backslash) defined?

Tags: ruby, documentation

I often have trouble finding esoterica in the Ruby docs, and this is a case in point. Where in the official docs can I read up on using a backslash character `\` to indicate line and/or string continuation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html

> Ruby programs are sequence of expressions. Each expression are delimited by semicolons(;) or newlines. Backslashes at the end of line does not terminate expression.

https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/ProgrammingRuby/book/language.html

> You can also put a backslash at the end of a line to continue it onto the next.

https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/misc.html

> If a line ends with a backslash (`\`), the linefeed following it is ignored; this allows you to have a single logical line that spans several lines.

https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Tutorial/part_02/loops.html

> You can make lines "wrap around" by putting a backslash - `\` - at the very end of the line.

Comment: I think my failure to find this was that I searched for "continuation" or "line continu" or the actual `\ ` character, and didn't think to search for `backslash`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the "most official" place this is documented is in Section 8.4 *Whitespace* of the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html):

> ```
> whitespace ::
>    0x09 | 0x0b | 0x0c | 0x0d | 0x20 | line-terminator-escape-sequence
>
> line-terminator-escape-sequence ::
>    \ line-terminator
> ```

Where `line-terminator` in turn is defined in Section 8.3 *Line terminators* as follows:

> ```
> line-terminator ::
>    0x0d? 0x0a
> ```

[Note: the `?` is supposed to be superscript, indicating optionality, like this: `0x0d`<sup>?</sup>, but that is hard to write in a code block.]

So, put the two together, and it says that a backslash followed by LF or CRLF is considered whitespace.

Comment: Excellent answer.